# The configured apiVersion 48.0 is not supported for this org. The max apiVersion is 47.0

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm trying to access version 48.0 of the API so that I can create CalendarView records

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_calendarview.htm

Running `sfdx force:org:create` however results in the error `The configured apiVersion 48.0 is not supported for this org. The max apiVersion is 47.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll only be able to use API version 48.0 once your org is upgraded to Spring '20. Spring '20 will be available on all orgs on [February 17](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2020/01/spring-20-release-preview.html).

If you want to know when your specific org goes to Spring '20, find your instance (in Setup->Company Information), then look it up on [status.salesforce.com](https://status.salesforce.com/) and select Maintenance to find the Spring '20 upgrade date.

Note that if you are working with scratch orgs, the relevant upgrade date is that of your Dev Hub org.